# SELECT funciona no phpMyAdmin mas na aplicação php o mesmo SELECT não funciona

Tags: php, select, chave-estrangeira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Eu tenho uma tabela encomenda com duas chaves estrangeiras, remetente e destinatário que é o idPessoa chave primária  da tabela pessoa. Quando realizo o SELECT no phpMyAdmin o resultado sai correto. Porém na minha aplicação o nome do remetente e destinatário sai igual. Vejam a imagem

Comment: Sem você postar a query utilizada na aplicação fica difícil saber o que está errado. Poste como texto e não imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, pela sua imagem deu para perceber que tanto o nome do remetente quanto o do destinatário estão retornando em uma coluna denominada "nomePessoa". Se a query está igual na aplicação, na hora de fazer o fetch do resultado você terá somente o nome de um dos dois no mapa de resultados da query. Sugiro colocar um alias para cada um dos nomes na própria query, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT .... reme.nomePessoa as NomeReme, dest.nomePessoa as NomeDest...
```